# Convert 8-bit image with values from 0 to 4 into 1-bit image with 5 channels (each channel represents a label) in python/MATLAB

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, image-segmentation

I have segmented/labeled image data that I would want to use as input data for a DL model. 5 labels are available in the images and the data-type is 8 bit. So, my files are saved as 8-bit images (actually ranging from 0-255), but the values for the labels have grayvalues 0, 1, 2, 3, and 4. I would want to input this in a DL model as an image with 5 labels. So, I aim to have 1-bit files with five channels, each channel representing a certain label. Do anybody have any tips for me how to convert my images to the five channels?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why don't you use `numpy` array with shape `(samples, dim1, dim2,...dim5)`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand exactly what you are looking for. Here are a few utilities which could maybe help you :

```
def rgb2bitVector(rgb):
    bitVector = [0] * 5
    label = rgb[0]
    bitVector[label] = 1
    return bitVector

# Assuming you encoded you label as a rgb color this way, changes it in a bit vector : 
rgb = [3, 3, 3]
labelVector = rgb2bitVector(rgb) 
print(labelVector) #==> [0, 0, 0, 1, 0]

def rgb2labelMask(rgb):
    label = rgb[0]
    return 1 << label

# Assuming you need to assemble several labels, this create a 5 bits mask :
rgb1 = [3, 3, 3]
rgb2 = [1, 1, 1]
labelMask = rgb2labelMask(rgb1) | rgb2labelMask(rgb2)
print(labelMask) #==> 10 (8 | 2)

def labelMask2bitVector(labelMask):
    bitVector = [0] * 5
    for i in range(5):
        if (labelMask & 1 << i): bitVector[i] = 1
    return bitVector

# Finally the mask can be converted in a vector as well :
vector = labelMask2bitVector(labelMask)
print(vector) #==> [0, 1, 0, 1, 0]
```